# How to change the position of group and children in ExpandableListView?

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I want to change the position of group and children and both of them go to the right of view.

Comment: Could you please be more specific or provide some images of what you want to achieve?

Comment: Yes.Like this:http://www.8pic.ir/images/99723034187959188798.png.  Group and children go to the right.

Comment: Do you want this permanently or at a particular event like onclick ect...?

Comment: I want to be my custom expandable listview permanently.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to modify the arraylist you are using to build the expandable list and call notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: Can you give me a example?

Comment: Hmm now suppose in arraylist A you have the heading/grps and B u have children/subgrps rearrage A and B according to your requirement and update the adapter of your listview. I would recommend you to try this out with a normal listview first so that you understand it properly as normal listview has only 1 arraylist